# Resizing iFrame depending on DIV size

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

Here's my code :
http://jsfiddle.net/d6j6e/

When you click on the gray little rectangle in the middle, you can drag it to make the DIVs smaller or bigger. A bit like in JSFiddle.

I would like to be able to resize the iframe depending of the DIV size.
So If I click and drag the DIV to be bigger, well the iframe size would adjust to the bottom div size.

Any idea?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove your absolute values for its size?

```
#divId
{
 height:480px;
width:640px;    
}
```

=>

```
#divId { /* should be "iframeId" */
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That's so easy...dunno  why I did not thought of that. Thanks again